# How to override a function from a class (parent theme) on child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, overriding

I have my file here

```
 -> theme_folder_parent/fastwp/fastwp.user.interface.php
 -> theme_folder_child/fastwp/fastwp.user.interface.php
```

I copied in my child theme the same file and I edited but nothing..

I have on my class this function

```
static function displayMenu($id = '', $class = 'menu', $echo = true){
    global $fwp_data;

    //$logo = isset( $fwp_data['fwp_logo']['url'] ) ? esc_url( $fwp_data['fwp_logo']['url'] ) : fwp_main_theme_url . '/assets/img/logo-square@2x.png';
    $type = isset( $fwp_data['fwp_menu_location'] ) ? $fwp_data['fwp_menu_location'] : '';

    $soc_net = $soc_net2 = '';
    if( !empty( $fwp_data['menu_social_media'] ) && is_array( $fwp_data['menu_social_media'] ) ) {
        foreach(  $fwp_data['menu_social_media'] as $sn) {
            $lu = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $sn ) );
            if( isset( $lu[0] ) && isset( $lu[1] ) ) {
                $soc_net .= '<li><a class="navIcon" href="'. esc_html( $lu[1] ) .'"><i class="'. esc_attr( $lu[0] ) .'"></i></a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    if( !empty( $fwp_data['menu_social_media2'] ) && is_array( $fwp_data['menu_social_media2'] ) ) {
        foreach(  $fwp_data['menu_social_media2'] as $sn) {
            $lu = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $sn ) );
            if( isset( $lu[0] ) && isset( $lu[1] ) ) {
                $soc_net2 .= '<li><a class="navIcon" href="'. esc_html( $lu[1] ) .'"><i class="'. esc_attr( $lu[0] ) .'"></i></a></li>';
            }
        }
    }

    $menu_markup = '<header id="header" class="clearfix">
    <ul class="social-list clearfix alignleft">
        %s
    </ul>
    <div id="menu-button">
      <div class="cursor">%s
        <div id="nav-button"> <span class="nav-bar"></span> <span class="nav-bar"></span> <span class="nav-bar"></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </header>';

    $menu_markup .= '<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul id="options" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
      %s
    </ul>
    <ul class="social-list clearfix">
      %s
    </ul>
    </nav>';

    $menu = sprintf( $menu_markup, $soc_net, ( isset( $fwp_data['fwp_menu_title'] ) ? esc_html( $fwp_data['fwp_menu_title'] ) : 'Menu' ), UI_getMenu( $id, $class, false ), $soc_net2 );

    if( $echo == false ) return $menu;
    echo $menu;
}
```

It's not a pluggable function, beacuse don't have `function_exists`. What is the best way to override this function?